# Docker создает сервер для проекта Django однако я не могу на него попасть

Tags: python, django, сервер, docker

Создал проект в Django и могу просмотреть его на сервере вбивая

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

Попытался создать контейнер в Docker. Тоже получилось, о чем свидетельствует наличие контейнера в списке контейнеров.

Однако, запуская сервер через

```
$ docker-compose run test python manage.py runserver
```

или просто

```
$ docker-compose run test
```

сталкиваюсь с тем, что сервер запускается, но по `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` туда зайти не могу.

Работаю в DockerToolbox на windows 10 Home

Comment: попробуйте указать прямой адрес до django, т.е перейти по 192.168.178.90 к примеру